# How to create a shipment pdf programmatically?

Tags: pdf, shipment

I found how to create an invoice programmatically but nothing about to create a shipment pdf.
So far I can create the shipment for items but I have no clue how create the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already shipment of order  then you can create shipment pdf.
using sale  pdf shipment model ,pdf has been created.

### code:

```
if ($shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId)) {
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_shipment')->getPdf(array($shipment));
    }
```

### Create Shipment first:

You need to create ship first without shipment create pdf is not created.

Try below

```
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

$qty=array();
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $eachOrderItem){

    $Itemqty=0;
     $Itemqty = $eachOrderItem->getQtyOrdered()
            - $eachOrderItem->getQtyShipped()
            - $eachOrderItem->getQtyRefunded()
            - $eachOrderItem->getQtyCanceled();
    $qty[$eachOrderItem->getId()]=$Itemqty;

}


$email=true;
$includeComment=true;
$comment="test Shipment";

if ($order->canShip()) {
         /* @var $shipment Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment */
        /* prepare to create shipment */
     $shipment = $order->prepareShipment($qty);
      if ($shipment) {
          $shipment->register();
          $shipment->addComment($comment, $email && $includeComment);
          $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            try {
                $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($shipment)
                    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                    ->save();
                $shipment->sendEmail($email, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e);
            }

      }

}
```

See more about:[Programmatically create Shipment of a new order in magento](http://www.amitbera.com/programmatically-create-shipment-of-a-new-order-in-magento/)

Comment: Ok, I will try it. And this is also possible with shipment_items? I mean single items from the table "sales_flat_shipment_item" although there are related items which has the same parent_id.